# Using default values in TEIID throws TeiidSQLException

Tags: postgresql, default, jooq, teiid

I'm getting following error:

`Caused by: org.teiid.jdbc.TeiidSQLException: TEIID31100 Parsing error: Encountered "insert into \"form\".\"form_insertdefault_1\" [*]default[*] values"`

I need to fill table with only default values and manual insert works fine.
`INSERT INTO form.form_insertdefault_1 DEFAULT VALUES;`
I use postgresql database and JOOQ (InsertQuery.setDefaultValues()) for database-mapping.

Answer (score 0):

TEIID isn't a supported dialect in jOOQ, and I don't think that the PostgreSQL dialect will get you very far, given how specific a lot of PostgreSQL stuff is. I'd try the H2 or HSQLDB dialects, instead.

In any case, you'll have to do a lot of emulations, like this one, yourself, if you want to run jOOQ on an unsupported dialect. Instead of `DEFAULT VALUES`, which only very few RDBMS support natively, you can maybe list `DEFAULT` (using [`DSL.default_()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#default_())) expressions for each columns. This is what jOOQ would do for most dialects, anyway. E.g.

```sql
insert into form.form_insertdefault_1 (col1, col2, col3)
values (default, default, default);
```

Or even, just list a single column:

```sql
insert into form.form_insertdefault_1 (col1)
values (default);
```

Or, if `DEFAULT` is also not supported, pick an arbitrary nullable column that does not have a `DEFAULT` expression attached to its definition, and insert `NULL`, there:

```sql
insert into form.form_insertdefault_1 (nullable_non_defaulted_column)
values (null);
```

Comment: Hi Lukas, thank you for your thorough and prompt answer. I never expected such a quick response!
DEFAULT is not supported either, so I went with inserting NULLs.